# Is it possible, using PHPUnit mock objects, to expect a call to a magic __call() method?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, magic-methods

I've got a mock object in a test. The real object, PageRepository, implements a magic method using __call(), so if you call $pageRepository->findOneByXXXX($value_of_field_XXXX), it will search the database for records matching that parameter.

Is there a way to mock that method?

The real method call would look something like this:

```
$homepage = $pageRepository->findOneBySlug('homepage');
```

The test would look like this:

```
$mockPageRepository->expects($this->any())
    ->method('findOneBySlug')
    ->will($this->returnValue(new Page()));
```

But it doesn't work -- PHPUnit doesn't spot the method call. The only way to get it to see the method is to define the method explicitly in PageRepository.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

PHPUnit's `getMock()` takes a second argument, an array with the names of methods to be mocked.
If you include a method name in this array, the mock object will contain a method with that name, which `expects()` and friends will work on.

This applies even for methods that are not defined in the "real" class, so something like the following should do the trick:

```
$mockPageRepository = $this->getMock('PageRepository', array('findOneBySlug'));
```

Keep in mind that you'll have to explicitly include any other methods that also need to be mocked, since *only* the methods named in the array are defined for the mock object.

Comment: Note that, if you need to do complex things via a mock builder (e.g. disable the original constructor) then you have to call `setMethods()` explicitly e.g. `$this->getMockBuilder('ClassName')->setMethods(['findById'])->getMock();` because `getMock()` on the *builder* doesn't take any arguments.

Answer (score 5):

I found better way to do this. Still not perfect, but you don't have to specify all mocking class methods by hand, only magic methods:

```
    $methods = get_class_methods(PageRepository::class);
    $methods[] = 'findOneBySlug';
    $pageRepositoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder(PageRepository::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->disableOriginalClone()
        ->disableArgumentCloning()
        ->disallowMockingUnknownTypes()
        ->setMethods($methods)
        ->getMock();
```