# PHPUnit stub only works for the first method

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to stub Amazon's instance metadata class because it calls an internal URL that only works within an EC2 instance and can't be called from outside. My problem is that the method "send" is not recognized. The method "get" works fine though. This is the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Stub\Amazon\StubInstanceMetadata::send() in ...etc, etc`

```
    $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('Aws\Common\InstanceMetadata\InstanceMetadataClient')
                 ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                 ->getMock();

    $stub->expects($this->any())
         ->method('get')
         ->will($this->returnValue($this));

    $stub->expects($this->any())
         ->method('send')
         ->will($this->returnValue(json_encode(array('test' => 'value'))));
```

EDIT: This ended up being a combination of two different issues. The first one being the one pointed out by @fab. The second being that to return a reference to $this, PHPUnit has it's very own method, so I should have done this:

```
    $stub->expects($this->any())
         ->method('get')
         ->will($this->returnSelf()); // don't use returnValue() here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the original class but it looks like `send` is not actually a method of it but rather called via magic `__call`. So if you want to mock it, you will have to do it explicitly:

```
...->getMock(array('get', 'send'));
```

Comment: You are right! It's not an actual method but this solution doesn't work either :( I've also tried specifying methods manually via `$this->setMethods(array('get', 'send'))` to no avail. This is getting very frustrating!

Comment: Right, with the `MockBuilder` it should have been `setMethods()`. If that does not work, I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: using setMethods() or ->getMock(array('get', 'send')) just returns the class with  only those methods stubbed. If you don't provide setMethods(), or the array with methods, all public methods will be stubbed by default.

Comment: @qrazi yes. And those two methods were needed. The problem with the default setting is that `send` was not a (explicit) public method but invoked `__call`.

Comment: I just added my comment to point out that not specifying should stub those two methods as well as specifically specifying what methods to stub. Since by default all methods are stubbed.

Comment: No, *in this case* it should not. Please read my comment again... More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210695/is-it-possible-using-phpunit-mock-objects-to-expect-a-call-to-a-magic-call

Comment: @fab, see my edit for the solution. Still, marked your answer as correct as it pointed me in the right direction.